# Can somebody help me understand byte arrays in python for the following sample code that was uses byte arrays to generate a large integer?

Tags: python, arrays, endianness

I am having trouble understanding what the `from_bytes()` method in python is doing exactly for the following instance of the code. Especially how does creating a byte array that starts with 255 and is succeeded by 25 zeroes give rise to an integer value.

I am especially interested in understanding the internal workings of the following line 
`int.from_bytes(byte_seed, byteorder="big", signed=False)`
in the code:

```
def test_base_hash_from_wisconsin(self):
    q: int = pow(2, 256) - 189
    q_static = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639747

    # Verify the correct value for q is used
    self.assertEqual(q, q_static)

    # Create a byte array with 0xff & 25 zeroes
    byte_seed = bytes([
        255,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0,
    ])

    # convert the byte array to an integer deterministically
    as_int = int.from_bytes(byte_seed, byteorder="big", signed=False)

    print(as_int)

    # take the integer mod q
    base_hash = as_int % q

    print(base_hash)

    self.assertEqual(base_hash, as_int)

    self.assertEqual(
        base_hash, 409769201286042520263200333546996463643161763414612173001850880
    )
```

This is the original C code for doing the same thing:

```
void Crypto_hash_reduce(struct hash *out, raw_hash bytes)
{
    mpz_import(out->digest, HASH_DIGEST_SIZE_BYTES / 8, 1, 8, 0, 0, bytes);
    mod_q(out->digest, out->digest);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about `from_bytes`? Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes?

Comment: I dont understand how the byte array, which looks like a normal array of integers<255 gets converted.

Answer (score 1):

Integers are saved as a series of 0 and 1 in the memory, eg:

> Unsigned int

```
0 -> 00000000 00000000
1 -> 00000000 00000001
2 -> 00000000 00000010
3 -> 00000000 00000011
...
65536 -> 11111111 11111111
```

> Signed int

```
-32768 -> 10000000 00000000
 ...
-2     -> 11111111 11111110
-1     -> 11111111 11111111
 0     -> 00000000 00000000
 1     -> 00000000 00000001
 2     -> 00000000 00000010
 3     -> 00000000 00000011
 ...
 32767 -> 01111111 11111111
```

Now i've used the "big endian" type of decoding, where the most significant byte comes first.

There is also the "little endian":

> Unsigned int (little endian)

```
0 -> 00000000 00000000
1 -> 00000001 00000000
2 -> 00000010 00000000
3 -> 00000011 00000000
...
65536 -> 11111111 11111111
```

Note how the bytes just swapped, but the bit order inside the bytes is the same.

What `int.from_bytes` does is simply turning a series of 0 and 1 into an integer, using this exact protocol

If you want to understand more on this subject search for keywords like `binary number`, `endianness`, or consult links like

- http://statmath.wu.ac.at/courses/data-analysis/itdtHTML/node55.html
- https://medium.com/@luischaparroc/integer-numbers-storage-in-computer-memory-47af4b59009

Comment: Thanks for the help.